# Issue getting $_POST from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I made a form with multiple checkboxes in it, as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose rooms:</label>
                <ul id="scegli_camere">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="101" > Camera 101</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="102" > Camera 102</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">                          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Modify</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

After the submission of the form, if no one of the checkbox is checked I get an empty array, while if one is checked, I get the POST as follows:

```
Array(
    [rooms] => 
)
```

Why is $_POST['rooms'] always empty?

Comment: I would like to see your complete form generation script. The `enctype` indicates there is more to see (file upload :p). Maybe one of the other input fields is triggering the error.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `camere` in the code !

Comment: @PeterBlue sorry, my mistake in writing the question, now its ok

Comment: @LaVomit here it is the entire code:

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted the code in your question and works well well on my  machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem found.
In a previous part of the code, there was an include of a config file, where the following code generate the problem:

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $_POST[$key] =  trim(addslashes($value));
            }
        }

    if (isset($_GET)) {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            $_GET[$key] = trim(addslashes($value));
        }
    }   
}
```

Removing it, the form works!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. This is working fine in my environment and i am getting the checked values.You can debug two things-

1. Wheather the checkbox is being checked or not while submitting the form
2. print_r($_POST) this will print the full post array.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the collection process, there is something wrong . Try to

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

or try to change "checkbox" for "text" only for see if not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code step by step. Check your values in console, or print them:

```
foreach($room_numbers as $room_number){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="'.$room_number.'">' . $room_number;
}
```

If its all fine, use var_dump to check $_POST variable

Comment: I've simplified the code as reported, but the problem is still present.
Here it is the var_dump($_POST)
array(1) {
  ["rooms"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. If you have no file-upload, just remove it and you can define your form as you did.

Comment: Even without it I have the same problem

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3paxeL/). The textarea shows you what will be sent to your server. Are you sure you are not editing your `$_POST`-global somewhere before your form validation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose rooms:</label>
                <ul id="scegli_camere">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="101" > Camera 101</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="102" > Camera 102</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">                          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Modify</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['rooms']))
{
    $data=$_POST['rooms'];
foreach($data as $t)
{
    echo "<br />".$t;
}
}
?>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This is rather crude but it should work. On the form :-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room101" value="1">Camera 101
<input type="checkbox" name="room102" value="1">Camera 102
```

In the PHP code :-

```
$room101 = (int) $_POST['room101'];
$room102 = (int) $_POST['room102'];
```

The two variables will have either 1 (Selected) or 0 (Not selected)

You could make the two variables an array if there are lots of cameras.